# How do you disable warning and error popups in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

The below popups have started showing up recently in vscode. Is there a way to turn these off? I couldn't find an option for it in settings.json

I already use the problems menu in vscode a lot which has a full list of warnings/errors, so I don't need an additional popup telling me what's wrong.

[image: Popup example]

Comment: Discussion on github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/41767

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the answer below back in July and then an overeager moderator deleted it today:

> I believe this error is coming from an extension you have installed. Please try tracking down which extension is the root cause and opening an issue against them

This is the correct answer and the poster found that the prettier extension was causing this issue.

We do not provide a means to turn off or suppress these error messages because they are errors and will impact the VS Code experience. If you are seeing an error, file an issue against the extension that is causing it or VS Code itself if you believe the issue is not caused by an extension

Comment: If you have feedback on the behavior, post it to the VS Code repo (or even better, to the extension that triggers this warning/error). My answer describes how VS Code works today. You don't have to like it but this is how it works