# Can you disable popup windows (notifications) in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, popup

The one thing I really dislike about VS code are the popup windows which come with certain extensions. It is like browsing the internet without an ad blocker. And with popups I mean windows within the editor.

The two in question are the arduino extension and the python extension. With every first .py I open I get a window with trash about the python extension.

If I plug in an arduino board, I get not 1 but 2 popups about the arduino extension. I found these so irritating that I disabled both the extensions entirely.

I can propably alter something in the extension's settings. But I simply want VS code not ever to open something autonomous.

There are also those small windows on the bottem right side which complain about updates and news stuff and what more. I do not even want to see a notification of updates.

*I really would like VS code to stop showing me anything autonomously*.

Can this be done?

EDIT: I just opened VS code and.... release notes. I turned these one of in settings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863450/how-do-you-disable-warning-and-error-popups-in-vscode

Answer (score 0):

With vscode 1.86 you can disable all notifications from an extension, see [Release Notes: disabling notifications per extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_86.md#allow-disabling-notifications-per-extension) for more.

[image: disable notifications from an extension].